# Command not found while starting the secured zookeeper CLI to connect to ZK server

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have configured the ZK Server to use SSL (signed cert, trust store,keystore, modified zookeeper.properties all setup done and good). Zookeeper starts and listens on the port 2182 for SSL requests and no errors in the zookeeper and kafka server logs.

```
#new properties added in kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
secureClientPort=2182
authProvider.x509=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.X509AuthenticationProvider
serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
ssl.trustStore.location=/path/to/ssl/kafka.zookeeper.truststore.jks
ssl.trustStore.password=serversecret
ssl.keyStore.location=/path/to/ssl/kafka.zookeeper.keystore.jks
ssl.keyStore.password=serversecret
ssl.clientAuth=need
```

Now to connect to secure zookeeper using ZK-CLI I am following similar approach. Create zk-client cert, get it signed, create truststore and keystore for the same. Create the properties file and trying to connect to ZK server but I get an error

```
Command not found: Command not found /path/to/ssl/zookeeper-client.properties


$ kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2182 -zk-tls-config-file /Users/path/to/ssl/zookeeper-client.properties

Connecting to localhost:2182

ZooKeeper -server host:port cmd args
    addauth scheme auth
    close
.....
Command not found: Command not found /Users/path/to/ssl/zookeeper-client.properties
```

My zookeeper-client.properties looks like this

```
 $cat /Users/path/to/ssl/zookeeper-client.properties
#zookeeper.connect=localhost:2182
zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
zookeeper.ssl.client.enable=true
zookeeper.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location=/Users/path/to/ssl/kafka.zookeeper-client.truststore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password=serversecret
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location=/Users/path/to/ssl/kafka.zookeeper-client.keystore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password=serversecret
```

Kafka Server logs at the start of the ZK.

```
[2021-07-16 11:27:38,676] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-07-16 11:27:43,760] INFO bound to port 2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
.....

[2021-07-16 11:27:43,819] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-07-16 11:27:43,819] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2182 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
[2021-07-16 11:27:43,821] INFO bound to port 2182 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory)
```

...

When I try to connect to port 2182 with the zk-client the server logs doesn't show an entry (probably because it is not able to connect as the command to initiate connection fails)

I am using kafka_2.12 version and it has zookeeper-3.5.7

What am I missing here? To me configurations look as expected and the zk-cli shouldn't throw

**Reference** :

- https://atsc.com.sg/docs/edp/7-security/zookeeper-mutual-tls/
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/zk-security.html

Thanks,
JE

Comment: BTW: I downloaded the new Kafka version compiled against Scala 2.13 and saw that the release has zk-cli version 3.5.9 I could connect to zk server with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your cli is running from older version that does  not yet support this parameter,  check your execution path , are you truly executing from the "current" version?

Comment: I am running the ZK CLI from the Kafka's bin directory $ kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2182 -zk-tls-config-file /Users/path/to/ssl/zookeeper-client.properties
 Checked the libs it's kafka/libs/zookeeper-3.5.7.jar and Kafka version is kafka/libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1.jar. Initially my doubt was the same as yours that I might be running an older version of ZK but that's not the case.

Comment: Can you share your zookeeper service file? I want to make sure where it is executed from, just to make sure it is executed from kafka/bin

Comment: I am manually running from the command prompt. I haven't set the kafka/bin the classpath.

Comment: But, yes I am planning to download latest kafka version 2.13 and probably will use only zk cli from that to connect to the existing zk server running just to rule out the possibility of older version of zk cli.

Comment: BTW: I downloaded the new Kafka version compiled against Scala 2.13 and saw that the release has zk-cli version 3.5.9 I could connect to zk server with it. Thanks.